# Real application scenario of using TPL Dataflow in MVVM WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

May I ask you to point me to some example showing how to use TPL Dataflow in MVVM application when TPL Dataflow is used in a data service.

In my MVVM application I separated application blocks to 5 different projects implementing model (domain and services projects responsible for updating model), view model (applications project) and view (presentation project - WPF application).

When testing domain, services and applications block using a console application all works fine.

For now I created Winform project to test what I will put later in WPF application, to test applications block, but nothing works.

I looked samples in Async CTP: (C# Dataflow) Real Estate, (C# Dataflow) Dining Philosophers. Well those examples shows how to use Dataflow but the code is put in the GUI, not separated in some service assembly.

My domain, and applications block are quite complex and I do not want to put them in GUI.

I read about TPL Dataflow as a successor for CCR and as matter of fact I already used CCR in my project couple years ago. The CCR worked for me in such scenario.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you're looking for? I understand you want to see examples of TPL Dataflow in an MVVM app, but, barring that, what specifically are you needing help with?

Comment: My naive understanding of TPL Dataflow was that it is similar like CCR where you setup your ports and activate arbiters, then any job/task you post to a port is executed by a scheduler on a thread, as I mention such scenario works for me.

Comment: In TPL Dataflow you have got ActionBlock like a port in CCR, so again posting a job/task to ActionBlock or to some BufferBlock linked to (LinkTo) an action block would execute your task. 
In my console application all works fine. Any job posted to action block is executed. 
When I use my service assembly from winforms application no task is executed. In my test I simulate one job execution (login to asmx web services using WCF client, where communication is done by async/await) and as well repeating task execution (my services queries asmx web service for market prices.)

Comment: The job responsible for a market price retrieval contains await TaskEx.Delay(1000), so when market prices are updated job execution is postponed for 1 second, and if market flag update is active, my service repost this job again for execution. This way there is no loop for market prices monitoring, but a loop is done by reposting the same job.

Comment: My problem is maybe that I do not understand how TPL Dataflow executes tasks, I thought that when action block is initialized a task scheduler is created for an action block, so some thread is created for this action block, when the action block receives a task then it is scheduled on the same thread, or new thread is created in thread pool. 

What I want to achieve is that my service should run on other thread than UI one.  The service will execute my application logic, updates my model, and when model data are changed, the changes will be propagated to my UI.

Comment: English is foreign language for me, so maybe what I tried to explain does not make any sense for you. Here there is a video showing my test: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRCilCVvELE
   My question is why this simple TPL dataflow code fails to run in Windows Forms application?

Comment: @StefanBelo did you ever get this sorted? If I were you I'd put up the question phrased as per your 2nd last comment (15.40).